# Redundant Entries after Insert Trigger is fired

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a user screen which takes installment as input, it is saved into installment table (`t_received_money_item`). Each installment is associated with its order number. Order number is primary id.

On installment table I have a trigger called `trg_t_received_money_item_insert_setReceivedMoneyUpdate`

It is an AFTER INSERT trigger. Trigger inserts data into a table called `t_credit_system_money`. However, my problem with the trigger is :
1. After inserting multiple installments into the table, redundant entries are inserted into `t_credit_system_money`.

for example :

If I insert values into installment table(`t_received_money_item`)
as 1000 amount for bill_customer_code = 1
then, `t_credit_system_money` will have entry with 1000 amount for bill_customer_code = 1.

If I insert two records into `t_received_money_item` as 1000 amount for bill_customer_code = 1 and 2000 amount for bill_customer_code = 2, then
`t_credit_system_money` will have entries with 1000 amount for bill_customer_code = 1 and `t_credit_system_money` will have entry with 1000 amount for bill_customer_code = 1 once again and `t_credit_system_money` will have entry with 2000 amount for bill_customer_code = 2.

And similarly 6 records in `t_credit_system_money` after 3 insertions in `t_received_money_item`

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `kikan_db`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trg_t_received_money_item_insert_setReceivedMoneyUpdate`$$

CREATE
   /*!50017 DEFINER = 'kikan'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `trg_t_received_money_item_insert_setReceivedMoneyUpdate` AFTER INSERT ON `t_received_money_item` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE new_order_no VARCHAR(15);

  SELECT order_no INTO new_order_no FROM t_received_money  WHERE `t_received_money`.bill_customer_code = new.bill_customer_code;  


INSERT INTO t_credit_system_money(
                                data_created,
                                process_flag,
                                data_flag,
                                bill_customer_code,
                                bill_spot_customer_code,
                                order_no,
                                amount,
                                amount2,
                                credit_update_flag,
                                delete_flag,
                                create_user,
                                update_user,
                                updated,
                                deleted,
                                created
                            )
                            VALUES
                            (
                                NOW(),
                                1,
                                1,
                                NEW.bill_customer_code,
                                IFNULL(NEW.bill_spot_customer_code,0),
                                new_order_no,
                                NEW.received_money,
                                0,
                                0,
                                0,
                                NEW.update_user,
                                NEW.update_user,
                                NEW.updated,
                                NULL,
                                NEW.updated
                            );

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Tag the correct dbms. This is **not* sql server.

Comment: Looking into your SQL code i see MySQL's code syntax and not SQL-server syntax.